# java networking using objectinputstream & objectoutputstream

Tags: java, networking

I made 2 small console applications (server & client) to learn how to let the server & client send multiple variable value's to each other using objectInputStream & objectOutputStream. However, my client programm just seems to get stuck the moment i ask it to create the objectInputStream object. Here is my code:

```
public class client {

static String key, temp, tester;
static UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();

public static void main(String[]args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //CONNECT TO SERVER
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1350);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    //INPUT
    System.out.println("Client:" + "Enter a message!");
    ui.message = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Client:" + "Enter a number!");
    ui.number = scanner.nextInt();

    //WRITE & SEND
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(ui);
    oos.flush();

    //RECEIVE AND READ
    UserInfo info = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();

    System.out.println("Server:" + info);
}
```

}

And here is my server code:

```
public class ser {

static String key, temp;
static UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1350);
    System.out.println("Server started.");
    Socket soc = s1.accept();

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
    UserInfo info = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();

    info.message += ", and this is the server's message-part";
    info.number *= 3;

    oos.writeObject(ui);
    oos.flush();
}

}

public class UserInfo implements Serializable{
public int number;
public String message;
}
```

To be clear: i don't get any errors, it just stops the moment it reaches the objectinputstream. Am i wrong to use objectinput/output stream classes? I also heard something about dataoutput/inputstream. Is that what i should try?

EDIT: with this new edited code it doesn't freeze or deadlock anymore, but instead i get this exception error telling me it doesn't know the source:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at cli.main(cli.java:33)
```

Comment: Can we see `UserInfo`?

Comment: It’s probably because you didn’t make your fields number and message public.

Comment: I edited it, and no i did make them public :)

Comment: @JacobB.: I can guarantee that you are wrong. Your guess would lead to a *compilation* error, not a run-time exception or frozen application. Edit: statement made before the OP posted the UserInfo class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh yeah that’s right. My bad

Answer (score 1):

> it just stops the moment it reaches the objectoutputstream

No it doesn't. It stops the moment it reaches `new ObjectInputStream(...)`.

You must create the `ObjectOutputStream` first, before the `ObjectInputStream`. Otherwise you deadlock trying to read the stream headers.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, that's what i meant, i made a typing mistake.